# How do I load all images using Universal Image Loader whether they're on screen or not?

Tags: java, android, gridview, universal-image-loader

I want to make my Universal Image Loader project work as fast as Quickpic. In order to do so, I want to start caching my images before they're ever shown on screen. Right now they only load when I can see them. Any ideas? I'm using their gridview